# Tool-specific definition in (System)Verilog, especially by quartus and Synopsys DC

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, quartus

I am writing a toy CPU with (System)Verilog. And there is a register module for which I am using tool-specific IP. `DW_ram` in DesignWare in terms of Synopsys Design Compiler. `Altera_sync_ram` in terms of FPGA by Altera.

Is there any definitions that Synopsys DC or Quartus Prime Pro would automatically pass to the parser to make one piece of code compatible for both tools?

Because if there is at least one such definition (say `DESIGNCOMPILER` for DC), the following code would be possible.

```
`ifdef DESIGNCOMPILER
     DW_RAM my_register (.*);
`else
     Altera_sync_ram my_register (.*);
`endif
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Synopsys Design Compiler supports the `ifdef` directive. Definitions can be passed to the tool while reading the design as in the example below.

```
analyze -format sverilog -define DESIGNCOMPILER MyDesign.sv
```